# SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I don't understand why this is happening

I Mention /Error Here in the code so you can easily find out

Any idea how to fix the issue?
Sometimes it works as normal without any error but some times it throws NullPointerException

Error Log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at com.app.android.Provider.PrefManager.<init>(PrefManager.java:34)
        at com.app.android.ui.fragement.PlayerFragment.addView(PlayerFragment.java:1901)
        at com.app.android.ui.fragement.PlayerFragment$25.onPlayerStateChanged(PlayerFragment.java:993)
```

PrefManager.java

```
public class PrefManager {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;


    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "status_app";

    private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH = "IsFirstTimeLaunch";


    public PrefManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
         pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);//Error Here
         editor = pref.edit();
         editor.apply();

    }

    public void setBoolean(String PREF_NAME,Boolean val) {
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_NAME, val);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public void setString(String PREF_NAME,String VAL) {
        editor.putString(PREF_NAME, VAL);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public void setInt(String PREF_NAME,int VAL) {
        editor.putInt(PREF_NAME, VAL);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public boolean getBoolean(String PREF_NAME) {
        return pref.getBoolean(PREF_NAME,true);
    }
    public void remove(String PREF_NAME){
        if(pref.contains(PREF_NAME)){
            editor.remove(PREF_NAME);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
    public String getString(String PREF_NAME) {
        if(pref.contains(PREF_NAME)){
            return pref.getString(PREF_NAME,null);
        }
        if (PREF_NAME.equals("LANGUAGE_DEFAULT")){
            return "0";
        }
        if(PREF_NAME.equals("ORDER_DEFAULT_IMAGE")){
            return "created";
        }
        if(PREF_NAME.equals("ORDER_DEFAULT_GIF")){
            return "created";
        }
        if(PREF_NAME.equals("ORDER_DEFAULT_VIDEO")){
            return "created";
        }
        if(PREF_NAME.equals("ORDER_DEFAULT_JOKE")){
            return "created";
        }
        if(PREF_NAME.equals("ORDER_DEFAULT_STATUS")){
            return "created";
        }
        return  "";
    }

    public int getInt(String key) {
        return pref.getInt(key,0);
    }
}
```

PlayerFragment.java

```
final PrefManager prefManager = new PrefManager(getActivity()); //Error Here
Integer id_user = 0;
String key_user= "";
if (prefManager.getString("LOGGED").toString().equals("TRUE")) {
    id_user=  Integer.parseInt(prefManager.getString("ID_USER"));
    key_user=  prefManager.getString("TOKEN_USER");
}
```

PlayerFragment.java

```
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {
        simple_arc_loader_exo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        exo_pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        exo_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        playing = true;
        exo_play.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        addView();// Error Here
    }
    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING) {
        simple_arc_loader_exo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        exo_pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        exo_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}
```

Comment: `getActivity()` is returning null . that means Fragment is not attached . Where do you have this code ? in which lifecycle method ?

Comment: Can you add the code of `PlayerFragment`?

Comment: Your context is null. Before creating `PrefManager` check if fragment is alive using `isAdded` inside fragment and in `onDestroy` make `PrefManager` null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@snachmsm @Bek @ADM @akhilnair Thanks for the reply I finally font out the error it on the Exo player in the lifecycle

```
`@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
        Log.v("VideoPlayer","onPause");
        releasePlayer();
    }
    releasePlayer();// add this solve the error same line in onstop also
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

your `Fragment` isn't attached to `Activity` when you create `new PrefManager(getActivity())`

try to put your code in `onActivityCreated`

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Activity is alive, Fragment attached, can create new PrefManager
    final PrefManager prefManager = new PrefManager(getActivity());
    // ... rest of code
}
```

it will be called AFTER `onCreateView` and this is a proper way. if you REALLY need to use this `PrefManager` you may optionally try this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final PrefManager prefManager = new PrefManager(container.getContext());
    // ... rest of code
```

**but note that `ViewGroup container` may be `null` in some (in fact: most) cases causing NPE, which is probably your case**

Comment: this.prefManager = new PrefManager(container.getContext()); i add this on create still got this error sir

Comment: in which method have you placed this line?

Comment: thanks for the reply sir I finally found the error it's on the Exo player